# How to make Facebook display all the OG images?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have created a gallery page, and I want to enable users to share it over facebook. To display the thumbnails I use OG images in the meta tag (dynamically adding them based on the link).

My problem is that when I share the link with the Javascript SDK as well as when I share the link by copy&pasting it to the timeline for the first time, Facebook will only display the first OG image.

If I copy&paste and link for the second time to a timeline (can be of another facebook user as well), it will display all the OG images, with a choice to navigate between them (left and right arrows), but same link shared with Javascript SDK for the 2nd, 3rd, nth time will still display only the first og image.

This is the relevant part of my page construction:

```
echo"
 <meta property='fb:app_id'             content='XXXXXXX' />
 <meta property='og:title'              content='My $VAR1 album' />
 <meta property='og:type'               content='website' />
 <meta property='og:url'                content='http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'
 <meta property='og:description'        content='This is my album with my photos from $VAR1.' />
";

foreach($db->query("SQL QUERY") as $row)
  {
   echo "
    <meta property='og:image'              content='http://linktoimage_$row[0]' />
     <meta property='og:image:height'       content='350' />
     <meta property='og:image:width'       content='1200' />
    ";
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do about that; Facebook decides how to display it. Btw., that you’re most likely creating an XSS vulnerability here (if that’s your actual code) is something you’re aware of I hope?

Comment: @CBroe  That's said.... :(  -  I guess you are referring to $db->query("SQL QUERY") as $row part....aware and no variables in the SQL query hence using query instead of prepare/execute statement. If you refered to something else please advice. If you wish to add your comment as an answer I can then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about that; Facebook decides how to display it.

---

Btw., that you’re most likely creating an XSS vulnerability here (if that’s your actual code) is something you’re aware of I hope? (I am referring to the part where you output `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` without any further checks or escaping/masking.)

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't realise that was still in the code.... I should take some breaker occasionally.